# Jenkins Cucumber report shows duplicate results

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, report

I'm not sure why I am getting duplicate results for the report. Some features
are passing but the same features show failed scenario.
Any help would be appreciated
My plugin

```
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber-report.html",
                //"junit:target/cucumber-reports/report.xml",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/report.json",
                "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are merging multiple .json cucumber file for reporting - all you can do is select the way you want to merge your reports, it will be done.

[image: Cucumber Report Advanced Options in Jenkins]

Comment: Can you please tell me the steps to make a change to your above suggestion? @PradeepBansal

Comment: Thank you so much @PradeepBansal. I did a small change and it is working as expected now.

Comment: If the above step worked for you, could you please accept this as answer.